# Порядок вызова операций в потоке stream (Java 8)

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть следующий `List<String>`:

```
List<String> arrList = Arrays.asList("небо", "земля", "облако", "космос", "звезда", "галактика");
```

Создав поток `stream`, отфильтруем элементы (слова) с длиною меньше 6 символов, например, и подсчитаем количество этих элементов.

```
long count = arrList.stream().filter(w -> w.length() > 6).count();
```

В каком порядке реально выполняются операции `filter()` и `count()`? В том же в каком они следуют в данном выражении?

Comment: Потоки ленивы (lazy) - это первое, что нужно усвоить при работе с ними. Операции вообще не будут выполняться, пока вы не вызовете метод-коллектор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порядок выполнения операций над стримами **не изменяется**. Но стоит учитывать, что  операции делятся на два типа:

- промежуточные (*intermediate*), например, *filter, skip, peek* и пр. Они каким-то образом изменяют входной поток.
- конечные (*terminal*) операции, такие как *count, forEach* и пр. Эти операции имеют какой-то результат или *side-effect.*

Разница между первым и вторым типами заключается во времени выполнения. Т.е. промежуточные операции **ленивы**, и они будут вычисляться только лишь после дальнейшего вызова конечной операции.

Более подробнее [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Answer (score -1):

Порядок потоковых операций не соответствует тому порядку в котором они (операции) вызываются в потоках ввода-вывода. Сначала в методе `count()` запрашивается первый элемент, затем в методе `filter()` начинается опрашивание элементов до тех пор, пока не будет найден элемент длиной меньше 6 букв.

Источник: Кей С. Хорстманн - Java SE 8. Вводный курс

Comment: Это описание слишком конкретного случая и не совсем корректно в целом.

Comment: @Nofate: за замечание спасибо, познавательно